# WP permalinks with .htaccess setting goes into redirection loop

Tags: wordpress

I have moved my site from a hosting provider to AWS ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx as reverse-proxy and Apache2. I am having issues with the permalinks.

in wp-config.php (without this the site goes into a redirection loop)

```
/* SSL Settings */ 
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 
/* Turn HTTPS 'on' if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO matches 'https' */ 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) 
{ $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; }
```

**I have tried the following:**

Permalink settings Custom Structure:`/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%category%/%postname%/`
With this, I'm able to access path `https://example.com/index.php/product/` but not `https://example.com/index.php/product/#something`.

I do not want to display /index.php in the URL so I tried the following:

**With the below configuration, the site goes into a redirection loop:**

in 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

mod_rewrite module is installed and enabled